Do not have the block "balance history" and "Unspent Outputs" for my address?
When I look up an address on mempool.space, the site shows four blocks:

Address (info)
Balance History (a graph)
Unspent Outputs
Transactions

I created an address last week and sent two transactions, but I do not see the blocks "Balance history" and "Unspent Outputs" for this address. What does that mean?
(The pictured address shows an example address with all four blocks.)


mempool.space only shows the balance history when there are more than two transactions associated with the address (source code).
Likewise, it only shows the unspent outputs panel if there are more than two UTXOs associated with the address (source code).
